# Ace Editor - How to find one or all instances?

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I try to get and set the value of an ace editor on a random website. But I do not know the instance names. Also there is no ID on any div.
Is there a way to find one or all instances, so that I can access the api like:

```
var editor = ace.edit("...");
```

Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

all ace editors need to have `ace_editor` classname and `ace.edit` saves editor to `<domNode>.env.editor` so the following  should work in most cases

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll(".ace_editor");
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    if (all[i].env && all[i].env.editor)
        console.log(all[i].env.editor)
    else
        console.log("can't get editor from" all[i])
}
```

This won't work for editors created as `new Editor()` which do not have `env`and for editors created in shadow dom, which can't be found via querySelectorAll.